# Visual Studio “attach to process” instead of run

Tags: visual-studio

When trying to run a program in visual studio it comes up with attach to process next to the green triangle, when it should be the name of the program to run. everything i tried didn’t seem to work even after researching everything

If you click the attach to process button it comes up with the CTRL+ALT+P menu and asks you to attach it to a running process. i installed visual studio on 2 different virtual machines and it worked fine but i can’t get it to work on my host despite multiple reinstalls.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED finally with no help from Microsoft
Visual studio was looking for the appropriate files in the C:\progra~2 folder (the folder used for 32 bit files) instead of the normal program files folder.
you can fix this by opening command prompt as an administrator and running the following command:
xcopy \progra~1\dotnet /e \progra~2\dotnet /y /i
This fixed the problem for me.